# PictureBox resize & paint problem

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, picturebox, paint

I want to show some graphics in a Winform app, it will be a stock's chart drawing tool. I think (but I am not sure...) I have to use a PictureBox, and using the System.Drawing.Graphics class' drawing primitives to draw the chart. I have started coding it, now it works more-or-less, but I have a problem with the resizing feature, as follows: when I resize the entire form, I see that the program shows the graphics then inmediately clear it. When I stop the mouse movement (without to release the mouse button) the graphics disappears!?!?

I made a small test environment to demo the bug:
Using VS2005, creating a new C# Windows Forms app, adding only a PictureBox to the form.
Setting the PictureBox's anchor to left, top, right and bottom. Add two event handler, the Resize to the PictureBox, and the Paint to the Form.

```
namespace PictureBox_Resize {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Ellipse_Area = this.pictureBox1.Size;
    }

    private Pen penBlack = new Pen(Color.Black, 1.0f);
    private Size Ellipse_Area;

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        Graphics g = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

        g.DrawEllipse(penBlack, 0, 0, Ellipse_Area.Width, Ellipse_Area.Height);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        Ellipse_Area = control.Size;
        this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

This small app shows the problem. It only draws an ellipse, but of course my drawing code is much more complicated one...

Any idea why the ellipse disappears when I resize the Form????

Answer (score 6):

Why are you using a `PictureBox`? I would create a `UserControl` for your chart and draw the ellipse in its `Paint` method, just using its current size. In its constructor, set it up for double buffering and all painting in the paint method.

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | 
  ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
  ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,
  true);
```

Comment: Why I use the PictureBox? Because it seemed to me logical using "PictureBox" to beeing the container for pictures and graphics. It has CreateGraphics() and the help of the Graphics class I can draw onto the Form.

Comment: but the point of PictureBox is to display an image file such as a .png or a .jpg. You want to draw your own graphics. You can get hold of a Graphics object on any control.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember from my C++ days - where I did loads of such image-stuff - you need to call the **repaint** method - or override it to fit it for your behaviour.